# ¿Cómo traigo un solo registro con Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Estoy haciendo un Login que cuando el usuario digite un código de usuario traiga el nombre asociado a ese código de usuario, estoy haciendolo con `Entity Framework` creando un método de la siguiente manera

```
//Llamo a el método cada vez que el código de usuario cambie y le mando el mismo    
public List<fNomusuario> cargarNombreUsuario(string codUsu)
        {
            using (Datos.comp01Entities db = new Datos.comp01Entities())
            {
                List<fNomusuario> nomUsu = (from usu in db.descfusu
                                            where usu.CODUSU == codUsu
                                            select new fNomusuario
                                            {
                                                nomUsu = usu.NOMUSU
                                            }).ToList();
                return nomUsu;
            }
        }
```

**El objeto que lleno**

```
public class fNomusuario
{
    public string nomUsu { set; get; }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Si quieres un solo registro, puedes llamar [`Single()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/bb156472(v=vs.110).aspx) en vez de `ToList()`:

```
fNomusuario nomUsu = (from usu in db.descfusu
                      where usu.CODUSU == codUsu
                      select new fNomusuario
                      {
                          nomUsu = usu.NOMUSU
                      }).Single();
```

En este caso, [`Single()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/bb156472(v=vs.110).aspx) te lanza una excepción si no encuentra ningún registro, o si encuentra más de uno.

Si es de esperar que a veces no se encuentre el registro, tal vez sea más apropiado usar [`SingleOrDefault()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/bb359429(v=vs.110).aspx), que te devolverá `null` en vez de una excepción si no encuentra ningún registro.

**Edición**

Esta respuesta es apropiada en casos donde tu consulta nunca debería devolverte más de un registro, como parece ser tu caso. El uso de `Single()` o `SingleOrDefault()` te protege de una consulta errónea o datos corruptos al lanzar una excepción si la consulta te devuelve más registros de lo esperado, mientras que con `First()` o `FirstOrDefault()` nunca te darás cuenta si esto sucede. Pero bueno, la diferencia no es tan importante.

Adicionalmente, si la idea es que solo vas a tener que manejar un registro, no tiene sentido que el método devuelva una lista. Lo mejor sería simplificarlo para que te devuelva una instancia de `fNomusuario` simplemente:

```
public fNomusuario cargarNombreUsuario(string codUsu)
{
    using (Datos.comp01Entities db = new Datos.comp01Entities())
    {
        return (from usu in db.descfusu
                where usu.CODUSU == codUsu
                select new fNomusuario
                {
                    nomUsu = usu.NOMUSU
                }).Single();
    }
}
```

Comment: Si alguien me puede ayudar a entender si hay alguna falla en mi respuesta, lo apreciaría mucho ;)

Comment: Tu pregunta la veo puntual y sugiere una solución, en este caso no veo nada como para votar negativo. En mi caso, cuando he llegado a dar un voto negativo realizo el comentario indicando los puntos de mejora. Sería bueno que la persona que votó negativo comentara su justificación

Comment: Yo tampoco veo nada erroneo en tu respuesta. +1 para compensar.

Comment: +1 La respuesta de sstan es muy correcta, yo para poner la guinda, solo cambiaría la consulta por esta sentencia lambda :  db.descfusu.single(usu => usu.CODUSU == codUsu).Select(u => new FNomusuario { nomUsu = usu.NOMSUS });                     Puede parecer que es lo mismo, y en este caso prácticamente lo es, pero es importante saber que los operadores, Single, SingleOrDefault, Firs, FirstOrDefault, Cont, etc, tienen una sobrecarga que acepta un Func<T,bool> al igual que Where, por lo que podemos sustituir el Where directamente por nuestro operador y no añadirlo al final. Gana en rendimiento

Comment: @PakKko: Hablando de detalles, aunque tu opción me gusta mucho y se lee mejor en mi opinión, cabe mencionar que en realidad el rendimiento con ambas opciones sería idéntico, porque todavía estaríamos manipulando un IQueryable, por lo que la consulta SQL todavía no ha sido generada. Y sea que se emplee `where(filtro) + single` o `single(filtro)`, EF genera el mismo SQL.

Comment: Esta clara la respuesta de @sstan

Answer (score 2):

En esta sección de código coloca primero `FirstOrDefault()`, luego lo conviertes a una lista como ya lo haces y listo:

```
List<fNomusuario> nomUsu = (from usu in db.descfusu
                                where usu.CODUSU == codUsu
                                select new fNomusuario
                                {
                                    nomUsu = usu.NOMUSU
                                }).FirstOrDefault().ToList();
```

Comment: Si vas a devolver un solo resultado, ¿para qué devolver una lista?

Comment: Porque la definición del método dice que se regresará una lista `public List<fNomusuario> cargarNombreUsuario(string codUsu)`

Comment: ah ok. Yo asumí que OP modificaría eso a `fNomusuario`. No veo para que lo dejaría tal cual.

Answer (score 0):

Para devolver un solo registro puedes usar la función `FirstOrDefault`. Sin embargo para factorizar un poco las cosas yo modificaría el método para que quedara algo así:

```
public fNomusuario cargarNombreUsuario(string codUsu)
        {
            using (Datos.comp01Entities db = new Datos.comp01Entities())
            {
                return (from usu in db.descfusu
                                            where usu.CODUSU == codUsu
                                            select new fNomusuario
                                            {
                                                nomUsu = usu.NOMUSU
                                            }).FirstOrDefault();
            }
        }
```

Saludos!